# Visual Studio visualize tooltips with markdown like in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, markdown

When I have following code in Visual Studio Code:

```
/**
 * # Test  
 * Comments in **markdown**
 */
function test() {}
```

then tooltip is visualized with makdown:

[image: Markdown-visualized tooltip in Visual sudio code]

Is there extension or any other way to reach same result in Visual Studio (not VS code)? I know I can use [this XML format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019), but I want Markdown.